# get def unicode string information in django

Tags: python, django, unicode

Hi I have a model that has a return statement like this.

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Car from: %s' % self.car_from
```

If I call the model and print it, it shows.

```
mymodel  = CarFromData.objects.filter(user = self.user )
<QuerySet [<CarFromData: Car from: CarRoom 1>]>
```

I would like to access the `self.car_from` in my view. So I can store the 
CarRoom1 inside a variable.

I tried this way

```
x  = mymodel.model.__name__
```

but that does not give me that string information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`car_from` is nothing but an attribute to a `CarFromData` Model. So, its value can get in following way:

```
mymodel  = CarFromData.objects.filter(user=self.user)
myobject = mymodel.first()
x = None
if myobject:
    x = myobject.car_from
```

Comment: .first() gives first object from the QuerySet. You should read the doc here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I tried to make an for loop thinking if there are multiple names the query set I could do this
for cfd in car_from_data:
            obj = cfd.first()

But that did not work, why?

Comment: What is car_from_data?

Comment: If it is Queryset, then there is no need of first inside the for loop. It should be  like:

cfd in car_from_data:
    print cfd.car_from

Comment: Okay figured it out!, I will post another question related to a similar python subject, hope you could help! Thanks!!!